# Undefined symbol when load a module to the target

Tags: undefined, vxworks, loadmodule

I got some errors when I try to load a lib to the target system with loadModule function.

Some symbols are undefined

```
Undefined symbol: __divdi3 (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: __floatdidf (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: recv (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: connect (binding 1 type 0)
Undefined symbol: taskSpawn (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: __gtdf2 (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: __floatsidf (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: __ltdf2 (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: recvfrom (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: socket (binding 1 type 0)  
Undefined symbol: __adddf3 (binding 1 type 0) 
Undefined symbol: __umoddi3 (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: __udivdi3 (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: send (binding 1 type 0)   
Undefined symbol: accept (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: __fixdfsi (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: taskDelay (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: bind (binding 1 type 0)   
Undefined symbol: inet_addr (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: setsockopt (binding 1 type 0)   
Undefined symbol: sendto (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: __negdf2 (binding 1 type 0)   
Undefined symbol: listen (binding 1 type 0)   
Undefined symbol: __divdf3 (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: __muldf3 (binding 1 type 0)
Undefined symbol: taskIdSelf (binding 1 type 0)
Undefined symbol: shutdown (binding 1 type 0)
Undefined symbol: gethostname (binding 1 type 0)
Undefined symbol: __fixdfdi (binding 1 type 0)
Undefined symbol: getpeername (binding 1 type 0)
Undefined symbol: getsockopt (binding 1 type 0)
Undefined symbol: __gedf2 (binding 1 type 0)
Undefined symbol: __subdf3 (binding 1 type 0)
Undefined symbol: soo_ioctl (binding 1 type 0)
Undefined symbol: tickGet (binding 1 type 0)    
Undefined symbol: getsockname (binding 1 type 0)
```

But all of those symbols can be find in the symbol table of the target

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: This missing symbols can be found from the static symbol table in the host, but I get an ERROR when I try to search those symbols with symFindByName in target shell.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? I've had some problems with GNU which did not produce a loadable object file (it contained a ton of undefined symbols). Switching to the Diab compiler fixed my problems...

Comment: Hi Lukas, I use Diab alos.I fixed this problem by using globe symbol table instead of system symbol table which includes a few sysmbols